import KML in a transaction an show in a map in GeneXus 18
i want to import a KML and show in map using GX 18 upgrade 10, web,.net with SQL.
Some ideas?
The ony think i find is https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/wiki?32408,Geography+data+type
but nothig about kml direct import. I need to store in DB to use to show ina map ant to send to google with api key and send a coordinate to check if inside the kml area.

Check the Map User Control and the KMLURL and KML file properties.
